# Deleting Jar libraries from Project

Tags: android, jar, android-studio

I created a folder named `libs` and added a **.jar** file to it and `right click -> add as library`.
Later when I wanted to remove that jar file I just did `right click -> delete`. But noticed it is still in the **build.gradle's dependencies block**, removed that line as well.

Should have done it in a different way?

I later added the same jar file back. Now there are no errors in the project, but when I try to run the app, I get 2 errors:

```
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\Users\UserName\projectname\appname\build\outputs\apk\appname-debug-unaligned.apk Path in archive: META-INF/LICENSE

Origin 1: C:\Users\UserName\projectname\appname\libs\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar

Origin 2: C:\Users\UserName\projectname\appname\libs\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar

You can ignore those files in your build.gradle: android {  packagingOptions {      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'  } }     
----------- 

Error:Execution failed for task ':appname:packageDebug'.

Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE

File 1: C:\Users\UserName\projectname\appname\libs\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar

File 2: C:\Users\UserName\projectname\appname\libs\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
```

[image]

I tried the

> You can ignore those files in your build.gradle: android {
>   packagingOptions { exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' } }

[image]

But nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you to `exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'` but instead you have `exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'`. Change it to the statement it's recommending to you.

Comment: Yes, actually such errors kept on coming 1 after the other and I had to add all of them. Forgot to delete the question.